# How to select an Autocad entity by entity name for use in autocad command in a lisp

Tags: lisp, entity, autocad

This might be something simple that I just keep missing but...

I can get the entity name but is there anyway to use an entity name assigned to a varible to have an Autocad command use the entity as the selected object to act on?

Comment: Make sure to 'accept' an answer if it is helpful or solves your problem.  Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

To use in "immediate" mode precede the name of the variable with an exclamation mark (!).

e.g. save an entity to a variable named 'ent' ...

```
(setq ent (car (entsel)))
```

Then at the command line, say for example, the move command:

```
Command: move [enter]
Select objects: !ent <Entity name: 7ffff716c80> 1 found
Select objects: [enter] ;; to terminate selection process
Specify base point or [Displacement] ...
```

Otherwise, to use in code (assuming vars p1 and p2 are properly set):

```
(command ".move" ent "" p1 p2)
```

Keep in mind, as coded above, any running osnap settings will be honored, and can be a "gotcha".